# Vertex attribute is not being interpolated at all

Tags: c++, glsl, opengl-es-2.0, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I assign each vertex a unique set of coordinates and i am expecting the fragment in fragment shader to have interpolated value for that varying variable. Problem is, in fragment shader value always remains 0.0. How can i fix that. I am using opengles 2.0 with glsl version 1.2.

Vertex shader:

```
attribute vec4 Position;
attribute vec4 SourceColor;
attribute vec3 BaryCentricCoord;
varying vec4 DestinationColor;
uniform mat4 Projection;
uniform mat4 Modelview;
attribute vec2 TexCoordIn;
varying vec2 TexCoordOut;
varying vec3 vBC;
void main() {
  vBC = BaryCentricCoord;
  DestinationColor = SourceColor;
  gl_Position = Projection * Modelview * Position; 
  TexCoordOut = TexCoordIn; 
};
```

Fragment shader:

```
varying vec4 DestinationColor;
varying vec2 TexCoordOut;
varying vec3 vBC;
uniform sampler2D Texture;
uniform int TexEnabled;
float edgeFactor();
void main() {
     if (TexEnabled == 1) {
           gl_FragColor = texture2D(Texture, TexCoordOut) * DestinationColor;
     } else{
            gl_FragColor = vec4(DestinationColor.xyz, edgeFactor());
     }
}
float edgeFactor() {
    vec3 d = fwidth(vBC);
    vec3 a3 = smoothstep(vec3(0.0), d*1.5, vBC);
    return min(min(a3.x, a3.y), a3.z);
};
```

Vertex data:

```
float vertices[] {
        p1.x - deltaX, p1.y + deltaY, 0.0f, //top-left
        p2.x - deltaX, p2.y + deltaY, 0.0f, //top-right
        p2.x + deltaX, p2.y - deltaY, 0.0f, //bottom-right
        p2.x + deltaX, p2.y - deltaY, 0.0f, //bottom-right
        p1.x + deltaX, p1.y - deltaY, 0.0f, //bottom-left
        p1.x - deltaX, p1.y + deltaY, 0.0f //top-left
    };
```

Barycentric coordinates i am passing (each set of 3 corresponds to a vertex):

```
// R 
    data[0] = 1.0; 
    data[1] = 0.0;
    data[2] = 0.0; 

    // G
    data[3] = 0.0;
    data[4] = 1.0;
    data[5] = 0.0;

    // B
    data[6] = 0.0; 
    data[7] = 0.0;
    data[8] = 1.0; 

    // B
    data[9] = 0.0; 
    data[10] = 0.0;
    data[11] = 1.0; 

    // G
    data[12] = 0.0;
    data[13] = 1.0;
    data[14] = 0.0;

    // R 
    data[15] = 1.0; 
    data[16] = 0.0;
    data[17] = 0.0;
```

Enabled :

```
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glEnable( GL_BLEND );
```

Passing data as: `glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);`

Comment: Which of the values is always zero?

Comment: Also show how you set the attributes.

Comment: Also add how you link the handles (shader variables) for these attributes and uniforms. And confirm these all return a valid value (>=0)

Comment: _attrSlot = glGetAttribLocation(progId, attribNameInFragShdr)

Comment: All three of the values are 0

Comment: glVertexAttribPointer(_attrSlot, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, reinterpret_cast<const GLvoid*>(coordinates));
}

Comment: There is no way you can avoid interpolation in varying data in OpenGL ES 2.0. So the only chance is your attributes are all 0. If you can post the OpenGL setup and Attribute loading code, we can investigate further